# Using ncf package to generate correlograms and calculate Moran's I

Tags: r, autocorrelation

I'm trying to use the ncf package in R to generate correlograms and calculate Moran's I for some data on archaeological human remains.  This script seems to work:

```
jomcor <- correlog(x = jomon$NCLat,y = jomon$NCLong, z = jomon$NCPC1, latlon=TRUE, increment=100, resamp=0)
```

But the output doesn't quite make sense when referring to the package documentation and I think I might be doing something wrong.

`jomcor$nlok` should call the number of pairs per distance class, but the answer returned is NULL.

If I call the object `jomcor`, I get a value for `$n`, which seems like it should be the same as `$nlok`, i.e., the number of pairs per distance class:

```
$n
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
14  2  8 14  3 11  4 18  3  6  6  2  9 16  2  2
```

but these numbers aren't right when checking the data, so I don't know what these are.  A value for `$n` isn't listed in the package documentation.

Similarly, I get `NULL` returned for `$p` however I vary the parameters.  I'm assuming that if there weren't any significant Moran's I values, I would still get p values, so is this just not working?

Has anyone successfully used this function?  If so, please help!

Comment: You're passing x=jomon$NCLat and y = jomon$NCLong which seems the wrong way round. That might not fix things but its a start.

Comment: Looking at the code of `correlog`, the returned list is constructed as: `res <- list(n = nlok, mean.of.cl...` so it would seem the `$n` component is the `nlok` referred to in the help and the help (or the code) is wrong. I think you are right to assume `$n` should be as `nlok` is documented in the help.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and for pointing out the error in the x / y order.  We've corrected that now.

Comment: I think you're right about the ``$n` being `$nlok`, but I still don't see how it's calculated.  We have 16 sites and in some distance classes there are up to 18 pairs.  Am I missing something?

Comment: 16 sites means there's 16*15/2 = 120 pairs of points. Those 120 pairs give us 120 distances which get divided into distance classes, so more than 16 isn't wrong.

Comment: Ah, thanks!  That makes sense.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample code in `?correlog` runs this:

```
fit1 <- correlog(x = x, y = y, z = z[, 1], increment = 2, resamp = 0)
```

Its `$n` return (which should be `$nlok`, or the docs are wrong, I've created an issue in the github repo for the package so the author will know...) looks like this:

```
> fit1$n
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
477 977 911 669 591 465 365 265 165  65
```

There are 100 points in this example data:

```
> length(x)
[1] 100
```

which means there are `100*99/2 = 4950` possible pairs of points. Its `100*99` because points don't pair with themselves, and `/2` because the distance and difference from A to B is the same as B to A so we don't double count.

The `$n` sums to this:

```
> sum(fit1$n)
[1] 4950
```

since its showing how many of these 4950 pairs are in each distance band. So that's all good.

The `$p` component will only show up if you do a statistical test, in this case there's the facility in the function to do a test via resampling, using the `resamp` argument. If set to 0 you don't get a `$p`, otherwise you do:

```
> fit1 <- correlog(x = x, y = y, z = z[, 1], increment = 2, resamp = 0) 
> fit1$p
NULL
> fit1 <- correlog(x = x, y = y, z = z[, 1], increment = 2, resamp = 1000) 
> fit1$p
 [1] 0.000999001 0.000999001 0.000999001 0.282717283 0.009990010 0.001998002
 [7] 0.001998002 0.018981019 0.011988012 0.069930070
```

You probably need to read the references (or the code) to get exactly what this is testing for though, it might something like the "null" is random reassignment of Z values to points... but that's a guess.

Comment: This is extremely helpful.  Thanks for taking the time to go through it to explain it

Comment: And all I ask for in reward is 25 magic stack overflow internet points which I get if you click the tick mark to show this answers your question!

Comment: Done with pleasure!